# How to show that $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $e$ be an idempotent of $A$, where $A$ is an algebra. Let $B=eAe$ and $P$ be a projective right $A$-module. How to show that $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$? I think that $Pe\otimes_B eAe \cong P$. But why $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$? Thank you very much.

Edit: I am reading the book [Elements of representation theory of associative algebras 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books/about/Elements_of_the_Representation_Theory_of.html?id=ayNHpi3tYhQC). On Line 4 of page 37 (I attached this page below), it is said that $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$. How to show that $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$? Thank you very much.

Edit: Let $P$ be a direct summand of $eA$. How to show that $Pe\otimes_B eA \cong P$? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: The extra assumption that Steve speaks of is $P$ a direct summand of $eA$. The statement you are searching for is proven in the beginning of the proof of statement (d).

Answer (score 1):

It's not true without some extra assumption---e.g., as is standard in Morita theory, you might ask that the two-sided ideal generated by $e$ is all of $A$, $A=AeA$. For an example where the claim fails, suppose $A$ is the algebra $k \oplus k$ for a field $k$, $e=(1,0)$ is the idempotent for the first summand, and $P=(0,1) A=0 \oplus k$ is the second summand. Then $Pe=0$.

Comment: thank you very much. I edit the question.

Comment: @Jianrong Li, Again, it's not true without more hypotheses than you wrote. If you look more carefully at the book, you will see that the additional hypothesis is that $P$ is a direct summand of $eA$. The example I gave shows that *some* additional hypothesis is necessary. If you edit the question again to put this hypothesis in, I will be happy to edit my answer to reflect the new question.